# how to delete one overlay when another is added in Xcode swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, overlay

I'm trying to build a function in my app which allows the user to drop a pin in a location and show a radius around that location. I only want one pin and one radius to show at a time.

I have worked out how to drop a pin and add the radius, and to remove the old pin when the new one is dropped, but cannot work out how to delete the circle overlay so that only one is show, around the most recent dropped pin.

Code is below for my map view controller. help much appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    //connect map 
    @IBOutlet weak var mapInterface: MKMapView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0] //all locations will be stored in CLLocation array, we request 0th element (the newest data which equals the most recent location)
        print(location)
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        print(location)

        mapInterface.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapInterface.showsUserLocation = true 
    }

    //add pin drop 
    @IBAction func pinDrop(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        //Pin drop annotation - get attributes of where to drop the pin
        let location = sender.location(in: self.mapInterface)
        let locCoord = self.mapInterface.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapInterface)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        //set pin characteristics
        annotation.coordinate = locCoord
        annotation.title = "Virtual location"
        annotation.subtitle = "Dropped Pin"

        //delete one pin once another is dropped
        self.mapInterface.removeAnnotations(mapInterface.annotations) 

        //add pin annotation to map view
        self.mapInterface.addAnnotation(annotation)

        //print locCoord to console to check it worked
        print(locCoord)

        //create circle attributes
        let cent = locCoord
        let rad: Double = 500 //adjust radius to make circle bigger.
        let circle = MKCircle(center: cent, radius: rad)

        //print circle to console to check it worked
        print(circle)
    }

    //add circle overlay 
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay.isKind(of: MKCircle.self){
            let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.05)
            circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            circleRenderer.lineWidth = 0.5
            return circleRenderer
        }
        self.mapInterface.removeOverlays(overlay as! [MKOverlay])
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation() 
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code in `pinDrop` method.

```
self.mapInterface.removeOverlays(self.mapInterface.overlays)
```

Comment: that done the trick! something so simple when it's in the correct place! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays)` will do the trick

however, if i were you i'd rather update the annotation location instead of recreating a new one and remove the old one

to do that you will take that line

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
```

and put it above `viewDidLoad` method

and instead of :

```
//delete one pin once another is 
  self.mapInterface.removeAnnotations(mapInterface.annotations) 
//add pin annotation to map view
  self.mapInterface.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

it will be :

```
if self.mapInterface.annotations.count == 0 {
    self.mapInterface.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: that makes sense - any suggestions of how to do that? use an array as I did for updating location? or another way? - as you can probably tell from the code, I'm still pretty new to swift so there's definitely room for streamlining!

Comment: i've edited my answer, if you find it helpful you can support that answer :)